# Not able to login after upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: system-installation, login, 17.04, login-screen

I've upgraded my ubuntu from 16.10 to 17.04.
After system restart I'm not able to login with the original password.
Any Idea what should I do now?

Below is the screenshot -

[image: eFailed to start session]

Comment: Can you add more details about what happens when you try to log in?  Is there an error message?  Would a screenshot help?

Comment: Thomasrutter - I have added the screenshot

Comment: Can you press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` simultaneously to get the CLI login prompt and try to login there?

Comment: I did that. I'm able to login using terminal but not using GUI :(

Comment: Looks like this is the root cause - https://askubuntu.com/questions/995993/recommends-unity8-desktop-session-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed