# Recommends : unity8-desktop-session but it is not going to be installed

Tags: unity, login, 17.04, login-screen, unity8

I'm not able to login into system because of below error.

[image: unity8-desktop-session but it is not going to be installed]

screenshot for the command `apt-cache policy ubuntu-session`

[image]

Can someone please help me how to resolve this package issue.

Comment: Add output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-session`

Comment: jdwolf - I've updated the information as screen shot. please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: The message about failing to download the changelogs hints you may have a problem with your internet connection.  Have you checked that?

Comment: Looks like I've connection to internet but not to ubuntu. created another question https://askubuntu.com/questions/996129/couldnt-connect-to-internet-after-upgrading-from-16-10-to-17-04