# Couldn't connect to internet after upgrading from 16.10 to 17.04

Tags: networking, login, 17.04, proxy, login-screen

I've upgraded my desktop from Ubuntu version 16.10 to 17.04.

When I try to login I'm not able to login. See [https://askubuntu.com/questions/995982/not-able-to-login-after-upgraded-from-ubuntu-16-10-to-ubuntu-](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995982/not-able-to-login-after-upgraded-from-ubuntu-16-10-to-ubuntu-17-04?noredirect=1#comment1608296_995982).

I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and able to log in through terminal.

After logging in via terminal, I'm not able to connect to Ubuntu sites:

[image: cant connect to ubuntu]

But looks like I'm able to connect to google:

[image: Google connection attempt]

Third related question I posted: [Recommends : unity8-desktop-session but it is not going to be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995993/recommends-unity8-desktop-session-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed)

Comment: What do you mean by cannot login? Are you can't login to your desktop, but instead you can to `tty` or about network?

Comment: yes. when I tried to login I get error saying Failed to start service.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/882812/544264) relevant for your problem?

Comment: @Yaron I updated OP question with links to two related questions he posted.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where http://changelogs.ubuntu.com comes from in your system but it is not pingable on my system and probably not a valid address. What is the result of: `sudo apt-get update` If you can successfully ping www.google.com, then you *are* connected to the internet.

Comment: @chilii555 - I'm asked to do `apt-cache policy ubuntu-session` command in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/995993/recommends-unity8-desktop-session-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed?noredirect=1#comment1608345_995993 and asked me to check whether I'm connected to internet. I'm not able to download updates from http://archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 ? (@chili: trying to exclude DNS errors)